# ¿Como realizar un score de Simon dice en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes, necesito algo de ayuda en Javascript ya que no soy muy experto en este lenguaje, el problema que tengo es el siguiente: Estoy realizando un juego de Simon dice, el cual ya funciona, pero me gustaría poderle agregar un puntaje que funcione de la siguiente manera: Cada que la persona de click en el color correcto se agreguen 10 pts al puntaje final, y así sucesivamente hasta el final del juego, osease hasta que la persona se equivoque en un color, un ejemplo: en el nivel 1 solo se presiona un color, por tanto su puntaje seria de 10 pts, en el segundo nivel, como se presionan 2 colores, por cada color se asignarían 10 pts al puntaje, dando como resultado 30 pts al puntaje final (20 pts de los 2 colores + 10 pts del color de la primera ronda), amenos que se equivoque el jugador en un color de esos 2 entonces el puntaje final seria de 20 pts(ya que solo seria un color acertado de los 2, osease 10 pts mas los 10 pts de la primera ronda) y así hasta que el jugador se equivoque en otro nivel, si alguien me pudiera ayudar estaría muy agradecido. A continuación anexo el código del juego. Si quieren realizar el juego yo utilizo el framework de Materialize y un poco de CSS para el estilo de los botones de Simon dice, para inciar el juego solo basta con dar click en el botón y después click en el panel de color cyan para comenzar a jugar.Gracias!

```js
 function restart(){
  document.getElementById('negro').innerHTML="";
  setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},400);
  
 }

 function start(){
  document.getElementById('boton').style.display ='none';

  iteraciones = 1;
  arraySimon = new Array();
  timer=0;
  turnoJugador = 0;
  seleccion=0;
 }

  // Generador random de secuencia de colores
  function simon(){
   if(turnoJugador==0){
    document.getElementById("nivel").innerHTML = "Level: " +iteraciones;
    document.getElementById('negro').innerHTML="Simon Says...";
    turnoJugador=2;
    timer=0;
    arraySimon.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (4)));
    simonTurn(arraySimon[timer],timer);
    iteraciones++;
   }
  }

  // Turno de simon, agrega un nuevo color si el timer es menor a las iteraciones echas
  function simonTurn(color, i){
   if(turnoJugador==2){
   setTimeout(function(){
    switch(arraySimon[timer]){
      case 0:
       document.getElementById('rojo').style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
       setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('rojo').style.backgroundColor = "#8A0808";},660); 
      break;

      case 1:
       document.getElementById('azul').style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
       setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('azul').style.backgroundColor = "#0B0B61";},660);
      break;

      case 2:
       document.getElementById('verde').style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
       setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('verde').style.backgroundColor = "#0B610B";},660); 
      break;

      case 3:
       document.getElementById('amarillo').style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
       setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('amarillo').style.backgroundColor = "#868A08";},660); 
      break;

    }
    if(timer<iteraciones){
     timer++;
     simonTurn(arraySimon[timer],timer);
    }else{
     turnoJugador=1;
     document.getElementById('negro').innerHTML="Your Turn";
    }
   },710);
  }
  }
  
  function jugador(id){
   
   if(turnoJugador==1){
    
    switch(id){
     case 'rojo':
       document.getElementById('rojo').style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
       setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('rojo').style.backgroundColor = "#8A0808";},150); 
      id=0;
     break;
     case 'azul':
      id=1;
      document.getElementById('azul').style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
      setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('azul').style.backgroundColor = "#0B0B61";},150);
     break;
     case 'verde':
      document.getElementById('verde').style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
       setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('verde').style.backgroundColor = "#0B610B";},150);
      id=2;
     break;
     case 'amarillo':
      id=3;
      document.getElementById('amarillo').style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
       setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('amarillo').style.backgroundColor = "#868A08";},150); 
     break;
    }
    if(id==arraySimon[seleccion]){
     
     seleccion++;   
     if(seleccion>=arraySimon.length){
      document.getElementById('negro').innerHTML="Very good!";
      turnoJugador=0;
      seleccion=0;
      setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('negro').innerHTML="Simon's Turn";simon();},950);
      
     }
    }else{
     alert('Game over! :c </3');
     setTimeout(restart(),800);
    }
    
   }
   
  }
```

```css
html{
 user-select: none; 
 -webkit-user-select: none; 
 -moz-user-select: none;
}

#rojo{ 
 width:162.5px; 
 height:100px; 
 background-color: #8A0808; 
 float: left; 
 border: 1px solid; 
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#azul{ 
 width:162.5px; 
 height:100px; 
 background-color: #0B0B61; 

 float: left;
 border: 1px solid; 
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#verde{ 
 width:162.5px; 
 height:100px; 
 background-color: #0B610B; 

 float: left;
 border: 1px solid; 
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#amarillo{ 
 width:162.5px; 
 height:100px;  
 background-color: #868A08; 

 float: left;
 border: 1px solid; 
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#negro{ 
 width:325px; 
 height:100px; 
 background-color: #006064; 

 float: left; 
 border: 1px solid; 
 color:#FFFFFF; 
 text-align: center; 
 padding-top: 30px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" id="boton" onclick="start();"><i class="material-icons right">games</i>Play Now!</a>
  
   <!-- Panel de nivel y Score -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
     <p id="nivel"></p><br>
     <p>Score: my skills in js are poor u.u</p>
     <div id="negro" onclick="simon()"></div> 
     <br>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Primera linea de controles de Simon says (Colores Rojo y Azul) -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
    <div id="verde" onclick="jugador(this.id)">
      <center>
       <i class="large material-icons white-text">bubble_chart</i>
      </center>
     </div>
     <div id="rojo" onclick="jugador(this.id)">
      <center>
       <i class="large material-icons white-text">favorite</i>
      </center>
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Segunda linea de controles de Simon says (Colores Verde y Amarillo) -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
     <div id="amarillo" onclick="jugador(this.id)">
      <center>
       <i class="large material-icons white-text">insert_emoticon</i>
      </center>
     </div>
     <div id="azul" onclick="jugador(this.id)">
      <center>
       <i class="large material-icons white-text">grade</i>
      </center>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Fin de controles de Simon says -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias definir una variable con var, esto crea una variable que puede ser alterada y consultada en todo el ciclo de vida de la aplicación, es decir puedes modificarla según la lógica del juego tanto como sumar o restar e imprimir su valor resultante al finalizar.

```
var puntaje = 0;

...
switch(id){
case 'rojo':
    ...
    puntaje += 10;
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, gracias por ayudarme, entonces el código que me sugieres tendría que quedar de la siguiente forma? `function score(){
  var puntaje = 0;
  switch(id){
   case 'rojo':
       puntaje += 10;
   break;
   case 'azul':
       puntaje += 10;
   break;
   case 'verde':
       puntaje += 10;
   break;
   case 'amarillo':
       puntaje += 10;
   break;

 }`

Comment: Si, esa es una opción valida, para restar solo harías puntaje -= 10

Comment: Seria genial si marcas la pregunta como resuelta :)

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, solo una cosa mas, disculpa mi ignorancia pero como la marco como resuelta, en realidad soy nuevo en la comunidad y no veo como ponerla resuelta x.x gracias

Comment: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/cómo-funciona-la-aceptación-de-respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Puedes almacenar el valor en una variable antes de iniciar todas las funciones para que este disponible en todos los bloques de codigo y pueda ser alterada.

```
var n = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta rápida, si declaras una variable fuera de las funciones, se verá dentro de las funciones. Es lo que se llama "variable global".
Para mas información busca "Ámbito de las variables"